# Even after install the panadas I am unable to use it

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.9

after using the command:

```
pip install pandas
```

this is the message I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\pathu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (1.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\pathu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\pathu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\users\pathu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\pathu\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

but after running the code in shell

```
>>> import pandas as pd
```

this is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: What is your default shell/python.exe path?

Comment: Did you tag the question as Python 3.9 consciously or by accident? Because the `pip` messages talk about version 3.7.

Comment: I added this consiously because I am using 3.9 now

Comment: I've installed both 3.7.9 and 3.9.7 can this will work

Comment: its pandas not panadas in the title

Answer (score 1):

Could you try creating a virtual environment(`pip install virtualenv`), activating it(`path\to\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`), and then working with pandas?

Comment: I got a warning :

The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\pathu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Comment: why not do as the warning says and add that directory to the PATH variable?